# Grouping Items in Rows in an HTML Table based on certain Header Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'll keep this short and sweet. I have a table that prints everything I need it to just fine. What I am trying to do is group the data rows under Program 1 together so instead of Program 1 printing, inserting the data, then printing again followed by another set of data, I want it to look like the "Expected Results" table. There are going to be way more than 2 per program, just used that as an example. I have been stuck on this for a while and just cannot seem to figure it out.

**Actual Result:**
[image: Printed Table]

```
**Expected Result** 
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Program    | To                   |  Date     |   Approved | Notes        | Deliverable  |
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Program 1  | example@example.com  | 12/23/2018| Yes        | Example Notes| MSR          |
    |            | example@example.com  | 03/30/2020| Yes        | Example Notes| Meeting Mins |
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Program 2  | example@example.com  | 12/23/2018| Yes        | Example Notes| MSR          |
    |            | example@example.com  | 12/03/2017| Yes        | Example Notes| Meeting Mins |
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
    | Program 3  | example@example.com  | 04/17/2020| Yes        | Example Notes| MSR          |
    |            | example@example.com  | 03/30/2020| No         | Example Notes| Meeting Mins |
    +------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchTable()" placeholder="Search by Program Name" title="Enter Program Name">

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var webAppUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

function loadData(source, url) {
  return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
    .then((r) => {
      if (!r.ok) throw new Error("Failed: " + url);  // Check for errors
      return r.json();  // parse JSON
    })
    .then((data) => data.d.results) // unwrap to get results array
    .then((results) => {
      results.forEach((r) => (r.source = source)); // add source to each item
      return results;
    });
}
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  Promise.all([
    loadData("XDeliverables", webAppUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('XDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
    loadData("YDeliverables", webAppUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
    loadData("ZDeliverables", webAppUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ZDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
  ])
        .then(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
      const objItems = r1.concat(r2,r3);
      console.log(objItems);
      var tableContent =
        '<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Program</strong></td>' +
        "<td><strong>To</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Approved</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Notes</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Deliverable</strong></td>" +
        "</tr></thead><tbody>";

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
            if (objItems.Program == "1"){
                tableContent += "<tr>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
                tableContent += "</tr>";
                tableContent += "<tr>";
                tableContent += "<td> </td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Deliverable + "</td>";
                tableContent += "</tr>";
            }
            else if (objItems.Program == "2"){
                tableContent += "<tr>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
                tableContent += "</tr>";
                tableContent += "<tr>";
                tableContent += "<td> </td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Deliverable + "</td>";
                tableContent += "</tr>";
            }   
            else if (objItems.Program == "3"){
                tableContent += "<tr>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
                tableContent += "</tr>";
                tableContent += "<tr>";
                tableContent += "<td> </td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
                tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Deliverable + "</td>";
                tableContent += "</tr>";
            }
      }
      $("#deliverables").append(tableContent);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("Error: " + err);
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Here is the Object Array returned in objItems

```
{"Notes": "Example Notes", "Approved": "Yes", "Program": "Prorgam 1", "Date": "12/23/2018", "To": "example@example.com", "source": "XDeliverables", "Deliverable": "Monthly Status Report (MSR)"},
{"Notes": "Example Notes", "Approved": "Yes", "Program": "Program 1", "Date": "03/30/2020", "To": "example@example.com", "source": "XDeliverables", "Deliverable": "Meeting Minutes"},
{"Notes": "Example Notes", "Approved": "Yes", "Program": "Program 2", "Date": "12/23/2018", "To": "example@example.com", "source": "YDeliverables", "Deliverable": "Monthly Status Report (MSR)"},
{"Notes": "Example Notes", "Approved": "Yes", "Program": "Program 2", "Date": "12/3/2017", "To": "example@example.com", "source": "YDeliverables", "Deliverable": "Meeting Minutes"},
{"Notes": "Example Notes", "Approved": "No", "Program": "Program 3", "Date": "4/17/2020", "To": "example@example.com", "source": "ZDeliverables", "Deliverable": "Monthly Status Report (MSR)"},
{"Notes": "Example Notes", "Approved": "Yes", "Program": "Program 3", "Date": "12/23/2018", "To": "example@example.com", "source": "ZDeliverables", "Deliverable": "Meeting Minutes"},
```

Comment: You want to implement a classic [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break). Your data needs to be properly ordered by program to begin with, and then inside your loop over it, you simply compare the program of the current item, with that of the previous one. Based on whether they are the same or not, you react accordingly in what output you create.

Comment: @CBroe Ahh. Yes. I remember learning about that in MIS, but had difficulty grasping the concept. I have been trying to look up examples/tutorials and in relation to what I am trying to do and haven't had too much luck. Do you think that you could provide an example in the code or an edit? I need to do this for work and its been kicking my ass for two days...

Comment: it'd be easier to write an example if you shared what `objItems` looks like.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce, sorry I will add that right now. Are you talking about the Objects(Array) in the console log?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. how does that look?

Comment: Ideally you should share the data as usuable javascript (json) so we can copy it into an answer. if you right click on it in the console there should be an option to copy it as json.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. the only option that it gives me is to store as a global variable? I tried logging it as console.log(JSON.stringify(objItems)); and that didn't do anything. Suggestions?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. check most recent edit.\

Comment: that isn't json either.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. sorry. Now check. Figured out the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219339/discussion-between-zgoforth-and-i-wrestled-a-bear-once).

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. anything? I need assistance bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the Array/Object before running through the loop.

```
 var sortedObj = {}
    objItems.forEach(item => {
      var program = item.Program;
      delete(item.Program); //remove this line to keep the program in the item data
      if (!sortedObj[program]) {
        sortedObj[program] = [];
      }
      sortedObj[program].push(item);
    });
    
    //sort by deliverable
    Object.keys(sortedObj).forEach(key => {
      sortedObj[key]
        .sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.Deliverable === b.Deliverable) {
            return 0;
          }
          return a.Deliverable > b.Deliverable ? 1 : -1;
        })
    });
    
    Object.keys(sortedObj).forEach((key, index) => {
      tableContent += "<tr id='parent-" + index + "' class='parent'>";
      tableContent += "<td>" + key + "</td>";
      tableContent += "</tr>";
      sortedObj[key].forEach(obj => {
        tableContent += "<tr class='child child-" + index + "'>";
        tableContent += "<td> </td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.To + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Date + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Approved + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Notes + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + obj.Deliverable + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      });
    });
          $("#deliverables").append(tableContent);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert("Error: " + err);
          console.error(err);
        });
    });
```